# How do I style div like this?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get rid of many divs on my page so I wonder if this "tile" could be done without using one.

Something like this:

```
<a href="mks.html" class="big-tile big-tile-1">
    <h1>town<br>
    library</h1>  
</a>
```

**The anchor tag would have a background: url(big-tile-1) top no-repeat; I guess. Big-tile would have static width and height. But how do I style the h1? Can You help me please?**

Comment: If they're fixed size the whole visual can be a bg image, then place the text using padding? DIVs aren't really that evil though.. not when they aid maintenance and code legibility

Comment: Where did you get that example from? If it's from a webpage you could check the CSS there. As for changing the h1 just style it by going `h1{style-elements:value;}`

Comment: @Adam I made it on my own. But it's like div class="big-tile-text" etc. and that's unnecessary.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I have the same opinion on this but my leader programmer told me to reduce the divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this: **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UFUq5/2/)**

**CSS**

```
.big-tile { 
    border:10px solid #ccc; 
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    color:#fff;
    background:url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/");
}

.big-tile h1 {
    margin:0; 
    background:teal; 
    position:absolute; 
    padding:20px; 
    bottom:0; 
    left:0; 
    right:0;  
}
```

Or if you want the image in the markup and not as a background image  - you could do this : **http://jsfiddle.net/UFUq5/3/**

Answer (score 0):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/wgyYL/2/)

HTML

```
<a href="#">
    town<br />
    library
</a>
```

CSS

```
a {
    display:inline-block;
    height:450px;
    width:300px;
    background-image:url(http://phaseoneimageprofessor.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/iqpw29_main_image_.jpg);
    background-color:teal;
    background-size:300px 300px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-top:350px;
    padding-left:50px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:20px;
    border:10px solid #c0c0c0;
}
```

Comment: your missing the grey padding bra.

Comment: By removing the h1 tag, you are changing the semantic meaning of the code.  Google will assume that the text inside is not as important as text inside an h1 tag, for instance.

Comment: @SurrealDreams - its actually both valid (HTML4) and more semantically correct to wrap the `a` in `h1` than include `h1` in `a`

Comment: My observation was that it was a _change_ to semantics, not that it's any better or worse.

Answer (score 0):

technically, you wouldn't need to use the `big-tile-1` class.  but you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/RU23A/1/

with a couple changes:
1. add an image to the background url
2. change the font to whatever that font is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<a id="image-overlay" href="mks.html" class="big-tile big-tile-1">
<img src="your image">
<h1> town <br> library </h1>  

</a>
```

then your css:

```
#image-overlay{
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    border: 10px #999 solid;
    border-radius: 1px;
}
#image-overlay h1{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: green ////whatever your choice
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: //your choice
    font-size: 20px;
}
```